# What would happen to atmospheric vapour if the amount of condensation cores decreased?

Tags: atmospheric-science, nucleation

Some rain is said to form from atmospheric vapour around dust particles from sand storms, smoke etc. What would happen with the vapour if condensation cores decreased in amount?

Comment: Particulates of many sizes make it into the atmosphere from many different sources. One example would be the smoke across wide parts of the US from the fires in California/Oregon this summer.

Comment: @JonCuster Are you suggesting that I avoid mentioning nucleation core sources in the question? I am willing to try that.

Comment: Are you asking about a hypothetical atmosphere with no dust/debris and how nucleation would happen, or are you asking about contributions from sandstorms only, or what? Dust makes it a bit easier to nucleate a drop, but drops nucleate just fine without them, just at a different rate.

Comment: @JonCuster Let us leave it at this to see what will happen. I suspect a runway effect could occur since water vapour is a very strong heat radiation absorber. If you want you can describe why condensation would occur anyway to the extent that makes it fall like rain or ice. If possible also include condensation sources from incoming space dust.

Comment: In pure, nucleation-core-free air, water starts forming droplets nonetheless at pressures 3-4 times the saturation pressure (i.e. 300-400% humidity) and will rain out. Is this the kind of information you are looking for?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yes that itself is good enough, with sources or calculations. If possible also show further consequences like how that in turn causes increased  absorption of earth heat radiation to cause increased surface temperature and increased vaporization. Cosmic dust is probably the only dust type to vary. Someone mentioned de-desertification by irrigation to cause less dust and thus increased surface temperature. Sources are welcome.

Comment: This recent review https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-earth-053018-060401 is what I can offer you, where you'll find my above statement (requiring 800% humidity, not 400%, sorry) as 'well-accepted'. So I guess if you want to find the cloud chamber experiments this is based on, you'll have to keep digging, but this should prove a good starting point. As for the other questions, keep them separate, as it should be on stack. The influence of clouds on the photon radiation field is a complex topic in itself.

Comment: Cosmic dust itself is yet another topic. There are separate review articles on that, but I don't remember CD to be considered relevant for cloud formation.

Answer (score 1):

Aerosol particles (such as dust, SO<sub>2</sub>, black carbon, etc.) do indeed act as cloud condensation nuclei. However, the wide range of specific characteristics (size, shape etc.) of the different aerosol particles and the diversity of the atmospheric conditions in different locations and seasons, lead to many different and interrelated effects of aerosols upon cloud amount and cloud properties ([this](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar5/wg1/clouds-and-aerosols/) might be helpful).

In the period 1980-2000 it is widely accepted that anthropogenic aerosol emissions were significantly reduced in large areas of the planet, as a result of regulations against atmospheric pollution and certain cases of sharp de-industrialization (e.g. collapse of Soviet Union and "Eastern Bloc" in Europe). On the other hand, the decades of 1950, 1960 and 1970 saw a general increase of atmospheric pollution and consequently aerosol load in the atmosphere. So there are two historical periods for which the effects of aerosols are being studied. Most notably, increased and decreased aerosols are considered to have significantly contributed to "solar dimming" and "brightening", respectively (see [Wild 2012](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/bams/93/1/bams-d-11-00074_1.xml)). This is due to them absorbing and scattering incoming solar radiation, but their indirect effects, i.e. their effects through the modifcation of cloud amount and cloud properties, also play an important role. Due to their complexity, it is quite difficult for the indirect effects to be quantified, but the document from the IPCC report in the first link is a great summary of current (up to its publication) knowledge on the subject.